# How could I typeset this? (Horizontal and aligned cancelling)

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, arrows, grid-typesetting, cancel

Let's say I have a reducible fraction, like 77/33, and I want to show its reduction. I'd like to create something similar to `cancel`'s `\cancelto`, in that it overlaps the superseded digit, but  horizontally. See this image (a mockup I made)

[image: -{77}-> 7 / -{33}-> 3]

Ideally, the two columns of numbers would be aligned.

Answer (score 5):

This uses `tikz` and I think it accomplishes what you want. You can play around with the direction of the arrow, too. You can also play around with the arrow tips using the `arrows` and `arrows.meta` TikZ libraries (Sec. 16, p. 191 of the manual).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand\arrowcrosswe[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(o.base)] 
        \node (o) at (0,0) {#1};
        \draw[-latex] (o.west) -- (o.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\arrowcross[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(o.base)] 
        \node (o) at (0,0) {#1};
        \draw[-latex] (o.#2) -- (o.#3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\arrowcrossew[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(o.base)] 
        \node (o) at (0,0) {#1};
        \draw[-latex] (o.west) -- (o.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\crossfrac}[2]{
\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\arrowcrosswe{#1}}{\arrowcrosswe{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
    \arrowcrossew{333}
    
    \arrowcross{444}{north east}{south west}
    
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \arrowcrosswe{777} & 777 & \arrowcrossew{777}\\
        \arrowcrosswe{333} & 333 & \arrowcrossew{333}\\
        \arrowcross{555}{south}{north} & 555 & \arrowcross{555}{north west}{south east}
    \end{tabular}

$\crossfrac{777}{333}$

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I forgot the fraction part. This updated attempt uses `amsmath` to get the `\genfrac` command.

[image: Output, updated]